# Making more than one shape appear in different locations, sizes, and colours?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I am coding a game, I want to have the shape I drew out using glVertex2d to be on the screen in different locations, colours and sizes. All I need to have is display 6 spaceships. I got told to use rand I searched it but couldn't find anything sadly.

```
#include "include\freeglut.h"   // OpenGL toolkit - in the local shared folder
#include <iostream>


void spaceship(void);


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 400);
    glutCreateWindow("Spaceship");

    glutDisplayFunc(spaceship);

    glutMainLoop();
}

void spaceship(void) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex2f(-0.5, -0.5);
    glVertex2f(0.5,-0.5);
    glVertex2f(0.0,0.5);
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Comment: Alright, will do right now sir.

Comment: @Rabbid76 just for the heads up this was a template that I am supposed to use. Other than that am I looking for glTranslate here?

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL is a low level API and thus requires the user to do a lot by hand.
There are functions such as `glScale, glTransform, glTranslate` but these functions affect the whole environment and thus need to be put between `glPushMatrix and glPopMatrix`. For example I if I push matrix create objects and then pop the matrix only, objects created within those 2 function calls will be affected.

```
glPushMatrix();
 glScalef(2.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f);
 glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glVectex(-1.0f, 1.0f);
  glVectex(-1.0f, -1.0f);
  glVectex(1.0f, -1.0f);
  glVectex(1.0f, 1.0f);
 glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
```

Because this method is deprecated in modern OpenGL many people try to avoid it in favour of manual labour. The manual approach involves Linear algebra you can find out more [here](https://open.gl/transformations).

Hope it was helpful.

Comment: Oh so, lets say because you got scaleF which scales it it wont scale everything in the screen but it will only scale the stuff that is inside push matrix? and pop matrix basically ends it? I understand a bit more now. Will this be helpful for me to make lets say 6 shapes BUT they are randomly drawn instead of them being same location every time i run it?

Comment: Yes you can use it this way, you can replace glScale with glTranslatef to affect offset from origin(centre of screen). If you did this in a loop generating random parameters for glTranslatef, you would accomplish your goal.

Comment: That's were I am stuck. I can do a very basic loop. for instance I can do so the console could display numbers from 0 to 10. But when I try think about it in this instance my brain just stops
void render(void) {


 for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
 {
  std::cout << i << std::endl;
 }

}

Comment: That my friend can only be solved by practice and if you can make console do something 10 times you can make this loop 10 times too. Anyway if you want you can mark this answer as solution and I would recommend you to practice c/c++ to get used to the basic constructs before moving on, that would be very overwhelming.